# Как извлечь и распарсить данные используя Codable из такого Alamofire response?

Tags: ios, swift

Подскажите пожалуйста, Alamofire запрос возвращает следующий response. Поэтому когда пытаюсь распарсить его используя Decodable и JSONDecoder, выдает ошибку "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format". Тоесть по идее должен возвращаться массив json-объектов, а возвращаетя какой-то SUCCESS, который уже в себе содержит нужный мне массив[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно извлечь нужный мне массив и распарсить его в массив объектов класса подписанного на протокол Decodable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно посмотреть на примере этого кода. Вы делаете проверку если результат success то продложаем декодирование.

```
    Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .post, parameters: user, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: configureHeaders()).responseData { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            do {
                let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserResponse.self, from: data)

                // Some logic with user

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print(jsonErr)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```